# Past real condition

Tags: grammar

I'd like to know if the following sentence is correct (concerning the verb forms):

"If the Indians refused to convert to Christianism, they were killed."

As this is a real past condition, can I use preterit in both propositions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When referring to a past outcome, it is [common](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if%20they%20complained%20they%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) to use **if** with simple past in the *if*-clause, and to use simple past again in the main clause:

> If they complained, they were fired.
>
> If they complained, they got nothing.

It is a statement of a past fact.  **if** pretty much means **when** there. Those statements could be roughly paraphrased as follows:

Those who complained got fired.

Those who complained got nothing.

P.S. But "if they complained" could refer to a present-future possibility or condition:

> If they complained, would City Council change the plan?